# FaceTime: unable to answer incoming calls on macOS

Tags: macos, facetime

I have an iPhone and a MacBook using the same wireless network.

1. I am able to make a call on my Mac (Mojave) with FaceTime using my iPhone, the call works without any problem.
2. When receiving a call I get the following popup:

[image: FaceTime Accept/Decline Call]

However, after clicking on "Accept" I get the following error:

[image: FaceTime Try Again/Cancel Call]

I signed out and in on each device without any improvement. It seems strange as the connection works (I am able to call). I only have problems answering.

**Any hints on what I could try?**

Comment: Is your time and date correct? Also are both devices using the same Apple ID?

Comment: Yes. Both automatically updated and both in sync.

Comment: Are you having issues with other calls or just this call?

Comment: Every call. Outgoing is always working. Incoming is never working.

Comment: Have you tried a restart?

Comment: Yes. The problem persists since a long time. I did several restarts in the meanwhile.

Comment: Can I just clarify is the problem for all phone calls or just from the same Apple ID?

Comment: All incoming phone calls.

Comment: Have you tried signing in and out?

Comment: Yes I tried as stated in the question. On both devices (mac an iPhone)

Comment: Are you updated to the latest version of Mojave

Comment: Yes both systems are up to date.

Comment: Did you solve it?

Comment: @AlessandroDionisi Not yet

Answer (score 1):

Try rebooting in safe mode as shown in this apple guide: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201262 and then restart your mac normally.
This should clear the caches and fix the issue.

Source: https://medium.com/@ambroselittle/fix-call-failed-with-continuity-on-macos-sierra-e9e662ad6947

Comment: Link only answer may not be very helpful as the link are libable to get expired. Consider quoting the linked content as part of the answer

Comment: Could you explain why clearing caches would be helpful? Did you have the same problem and fix it using this technique, or are you just guessing?

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem as described above. I can make calls but can not receive any call from anyone. I have a new MacBook Pro so it rules out the possibility of the cache issue as described above. By the way, my mobile number is my AppleID.

Answer (score 0):

My iPhone was connected to the Mac via USB cable. Cutting the connection was the solution. Now it works.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem with a MacBook pro (late 2016, four thunderbolts) OSX 10.15.7. Can I call, but when receiving and accept it, fails.

I have connected my computer by WIFI and LAN simultaneously. But when I disconnect the LAN connection, keeping only the WIFI, the problem usually it's solved.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/319143)

Comment: Excusme @agarza, but I haven't 50 of reputation to add a commment. But are you sure? Is Matteo using WIFI and LAN connection simultaneously?